# How do I find the JavaScript referenced by this button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Here is the "submit" button in the form with no `onclick` attribute.

```
<div id="243c0bb6-584e-4d48-a8fa-4308cd632028" class="nike-unite-submit-button joinSubmit nike-unite-component blurred">
  <input id="d7e56d05-36e1-42f7-922b-d2979375007a" type="button" value="CREATE ACCOUNT">
</div>
```

I am more confused about the `<form>` tags **from the Nike website source**:

```
   <form id="nike-unite-joinForm" class="nike-unite-form" method="post" 
    action="javascript:;" onsubmit="return false;">
      ...
   </form>
```

How do I find out what is happening when I actually click the button on the page?
Using mouse-click breakpoints in chrome dev tools gives me a plethora of JavaScript functions takes too long for me to parse through.

If there are attributes or listeners added to the ID (such as a link to a script), I could not find them after using "Command-F" on the different attributes of the form.

The only other clue which I am not sure how to purse is that `method="post"`.

I understand that all websites are different, but my question is a general one: 
How do I figure out what the script that is being run when I click on the form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's probably Javascript that calls `addEventListener()` to create the submit event handler.

Comment: Does this imply that the `document. ... .submit()` is not my problem?

Comment: `action="javascript:;"` ?? Usually, that is the place for the URL where to submit. `onsubmit="return false;"` probably prevents the submit.

Comment: Your `form` tag is incorrect. The use of `javascript:` anywhere is ancient. The `action` attribute should be the URL of where the data will go.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The point of using `action=javascript:;`  is to prevent normal form submission. My guess is the application is actually using AJAX rather than form submission.

Comment: The `form` tag is what I've taken from the website.

Comment: Also, look at the Network tab of your developer tools while you run the `.submit()` code to see if the form is indeed submitting.

Comment: When I do it manually it submits fine, I'm trying to do this from headless chrome.

Comment: @Barmar The way to prevent normal form submission is to set `action` to `#` and then `onsubmit=return false` (if you want to do it the old way or `event.preventDefault()` in a modern situation. `javascript:` is prehistoric.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, the `javascript:` comes from the website I'm trying to understand, not my code.

Comment: There are literally millions of web sites that use outdated or flat out invalid code. Just because it's on the web, doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There are many different ways to skin the cat. `javascript:` is just as good as `#`.

Comment: @Barmar Is it? ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus Along with `onsubmit="return false"`, sure. Once you have that, it doesn't matter what you have in `action`.

Comment: @Barmar how should I resolve my problem?

Comment: @Barmar I understand. I'm just saying that I believe that after 2004, the use of `javascript:` anywhere in code is an abomination. ;)

Comment: @jaslibra  try targeting the submit button with a click

Comment: @jaslibra you need to read all the Javascript that operates the website, and figure out what actually happens when you submit the form. Then you need to replicate that in your node.js code.

Comment: @Barmar is there not a logical path I can follow to find the executed function? I'm not even sure where to start because I don't understand the syntax.

Comment: @jaslibra Every web site is different.

Comment: @ScottMarcus any ideas on what I should be looking for and where exactly I should be looking? I'm lost because I don't understand the syntax used on the site.

Comment: As several of us have already stated, every site is different and there's a good chance the code you are trying to emulate is bad code in the first place. It may sound a bit cruel, but the place to start is to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript so you can pick through the code yourself and figure out what aspects of it are doing what. We can't do that for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try this:</s>

```
document.getElementById('nike-unite-joinForm').submit();
```

This is from w3schools.com:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

EDIT:
Ok, I tried it myself on the registration website and it didn't work. Experimenting a bit with it I noticed an apparently random id is assigned to the DOM-Elements.
But I've found a solution:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("nike-unite-submit-button joinSubmit nike-unite-component")[0].children[0].click();
```

This works because the div in which the submit button is has a unique set of classes. So I get the first (and only) Element with this classes, and apply .click() to the first child element

Comment: That is exactly as posted in the question.

Comment: Wouldn't this just reference the same object?

Comment: @jaslibra: No it simulates a click on the submit button. The "real" form submit itself is handled by something else in the page, on this action.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Is this a problem?

Comment: No... I upvoted your updated answer (while I did not test it myself), you say it worked, I believe you. The approach is good. ;)

Comment: @jaslibra What do you exactly mean by that?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could try to change submit with click:

```
document.getElementById('nike-unite-joinForm').click()
```

Comment: The click has to be sent to the submit button, not the form.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: Since `action` is missing in form and `onsubmit` returns false...this is probably the right approch but targetting the submit button as mentioned